# Return SUM(column) from a table and SUM(column) from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables called `tblSalary` and `tblDailyExpenses`. In `tblSalary`, I have a column called `PaydAmount` that keeps the salary amount paid per employee. In `tblDailyExpenses`, I have a column called `Amount` that keeps the paid amount per invoice.

I want to return the total paid salary (`PaydAmount`) and the total amount of paid expenses (`Amount`) in a month.

I have tried this query:

```
SELECT
(
   (SELECT SUM(PaydAmount) FROM tblSalary WHERE tblSalary.Month=4) AS PaydSalary,
   (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM tblDailyExpenses WHERE tblDailyExpenses.Month=4) AS PaydExpenses
)
```

I am using Sqlserver Compact edition
where I want to return it in a data grid view as shown below:

```
#| Type           | Amount
-------------------------
1| Daily Expenses |  1200
-------------------------
2| Salary Paid    |  7800
```

Comment: It would probably be cleaner if you could join the two tables in some manner.  Do your tables have primary/foreign keys that can be used to join them?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: These are 2 different tables with no join between them,  I think what you are doing is the best thing that can be done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually think a `UNION` would be better to use here.  You can do something like this:

```
SELECT 'Daily Expenses' AS Type, SUM(PaydAmount) AS Amount
FROM tblSalary 
WHERE tblSalary.Month=4

UNION

SELECT 'Salary Paid' AS Type, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM tblDailyExpenses 
WHERE tblDailyExpenses.Month=4
```

This should yield what you are looking for in your data grid view below:

| # | Type | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Daily Expenses | 1200 |
| 2 | Salary Paid | 7800 |

Comment: Thank you very much Timothy G.